# Javascript & CSS Obfuscation/Minimization in Django Website?

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

I am serving CSS and javascripts in my django website, so how to obfuscate and minimize them.
1 solution is: To serve already obfuscated and minimized js and css.

can I have a flag set in settings.py that to switch on and off the obfuscation?

So, that I can develop on normal human readable code and serve the obfuscated css and js.

What is the standard method of achieving this?

Comment: Why do you want to obfuscate it? Minimizing *and* obfuscating don't go well together. You can't really minimize obfuscated code, and obfuscating minimized code will probably make it grow in size significantly.

Comment: I just want to obfuscate or minimize [Either one that makes it un-readable] the js and css.

Comment: Please feel free.. to ask what you want. Down vote drives people away, hurt sharing..

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ would fix the minification, so you have to choose what exactly you want.

Comment: obfuscating your code hurts sharing

Comment: @pastylegs I don't see the problem with obfuscating and then minimizing what you serve in production. If you want to share code put the uncompressed versions on github / somewhere with documentation and source control.

Comment: @Xeon06 When would obfuscating minified JS result in significantly bigger file sizes?

Comment: JavaScript and CSS should appear largely in static files; if you're using Django to serve the static files, you shouldn't be. If you're not, you shouldn't tend to touch them with Django. Besides which, doing it on the fly is inefficient and slows down your site. You should do it once, beforehand. (django-compressor, mentioned by Mark, can actually do that.)

Comment: Sir, minimization atleast saves space. And then talking about sharing knowledge not code. Then, as said I have an option to share (GitHub), but need obfuscation if I can't.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc [This obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) turns `var a="test";` into `var _0x926b=["\x74\x65\x73\x74"];var a=_0x926b[0];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [django-compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). It supports running your JS/CSS through a number of different compression algorithms (JSMin, Slim It, YUI, Closure Compiler).

Comment: It seems good. So, any other option and what about the industry standards ?
How does the industry does that ?

Comment: There are a number of popular compression algorithms so I don't think you can really call one standard.

Comment: I am using this, it working good for js.
Any suggestions for CSS - I don't want to include executables like tidycss ?

Comment: YUI, CSSTidy and CSSMin are supported by django-compressor for compressing CSS. CSSMin is a python port of YUI CSS compression and wouldn't require configuring an executable.

Comment: django-compressor just works on css and js. But css obfuscation entails adapting templates (because class names are used across template) so we will not have meaningful CSS class names when inspecting in browser. The same goes for JS. Can we achive this goal with django-compressor or another library?